# How to join another table?

Tags: php, mysql

Right now I'm using UNION to get records from multiple tables, which is fine. But I want to include the author for the specific post.

```
$run = mysql_query("            
SELECT article_id AS id, title, smalldesc, hits, coverpic AS picture, timestamp, member_id AS mid, type FROM articles
UNION
SELECT video_id AS id, titel, smalldesc, hits, ytid AS picture, timestamp, member_id AS mid, type FROM videos
UNION
SELECT picture_id AS id, title, smalldesc, hits, coverpic AS picture, timestamp, member_id AS mid, type FROM pictures ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT ".$postnumbers." OFFSET ".$offset."
") or die(mysql_error());
```

I want the following select to be a part of the code above:

SELECT member_id, picture, fname, lname FROM members WHERE member_id='mid'

I want to get the member from each post, so I can print out who made the post.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Hello Kermit, I am using MySQLi for most things, but I have to learn some things first. I will "convert" the mysql codes to mysqli. I have a website that is online right now, and I need this feature, thats why I'm using the "old" mysql :) But thank you. I will check those links out.

Comment: You seemingly have a typo in the second SELECT using `titel`. In this very instance prepared statements make little sense. Also do yourself a favor and when switching, use `PDO`, not the `mysqli` stopgap API just because of the perceived name similarity. -- Btw, you could also wrap all three UNIONed queries in a subselect and `LEFT JOIN` that with your members table. Maybe more readable.

Comment: @mario but only if explain said, that indexes will be used in the subselect as well ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got, as you asked, to join the members table to the three part queries of the `UNION`:

```
SELECT 
    a.article_id AS id, 
    a.title, 
    a.smalldesc, 
    a.hits, 
    a.coverpic AS picture, 
    a.timestamp, 
    a.member_id AS mid, 
    a.type,
    m.picture, 
    m.fname, 
    m.lname 
FROM 
    articles a
INNER JOIN 
    members m
ON
    a.member_id = m.member_id
UNION
SELECT 
    v.video_id, 
    v.titel, 
    v.smalldesc, 
    v.hits, 
    v.ytid AS picture, 
    v.timestamp, 
    v.member_id AS mid, 
    v.type 
    m2.picture, 
    m2.fname, 
    m2.lname 
FROM 
    videos v
INNER JOIN
    members m2
ON
    v.member_id = m2.member_id
UNION
    ...
```

to get this information.